# Laravel 9 "The BLADE Language Server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted."

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, laravel-blade, laravel-9, vscode-snippets

I have this problem with **Laravel Blade Snippets**. As soon as I install Laravel Blade Snippet(Winnie Lin) VSC give me this 2 errors
1- "The BLADE Language Server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted."
2- "A request has failed. See the output for more information."
If I click on "Go to output" it opens the terminal and this is showed up a few times:

```
"node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:368
      throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\MyUserName\.vscode\extensions\onecentlin.laravel-blade-1.32.0\server\node_modules\vscode-html-languageservice\node_modules\vscode-nls\lib\main.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:360:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:573:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:832:27)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at c:\Users\MyUserName\.vscode\extensions\onecentlin.laravel-blade-1.32.0\server\node_modules\vscode-html-languageservice\lib\umd\parser\htmlScanner.js:16:15
    at c:\Users\MyUserName\.vscode\extensions\onecentlin.laravel-blade-1.32.0\server\node_modules\vscode-html-languageservice\lib\umd\parser\htmlScanner.js:7:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\MyUserName\.vscode\extensions\onecentlin.laravel-blade-1.32.0\server\node_modules\vscode-html-languageservice\lib\umd\parser\htmlScanner.js:13:3) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'c:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.vscode\\extensions\\onecentlin.laravel-blade-1.32.0\\server\\node_modules\\vscode-html-languageservice\\node_modules\\vscode-nls\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'vscode-nls'
}
[Info  - 8:01:50 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart."
```

I've added the preferences showed in the raccomanded settings as shown

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true, // enable tab to expanse emmet tags
"blade.format.enable": true,         // if you would like to enable blade format

"[blade]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"
},
```

I've tried uninstall and re-install or restart but nothing.
Obviously in every .blade.php there's no auto tag generation or snippet of any sort

Thankyou guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Uninstalled that plugin and used a similar one